# a void function to fill the array by converting integer to binary

Tags: c, led

```c
int main(void)
{
/* Stop WDT  */
MAP_WDT_A_holdTimer();

 /* Selecting P1.2 and P1.3 in UART mode */
MAP_GPIO_setAsPeripheralModuleFunctionInputPin(GPIO_PORT_P1,
        GPIO_PIN1 | GPIO_PIN2 | GPIO_PIN3, GPIO_PRIMARY_MODULE_FUNCTION);

/* Setting DCO to 12MHz */
CS_setDCOCenteredFrequency(CS_DCO_FREQUENCY_12);

    /* Configuring UART Module */
MAP_UART_initModule(EUSCI_A0_BASE, &uartConfig);

/* Enable UART module */
MAP_UART_enableModule(EUSCI_A0_BASE);

/* Configuring GPIO2.4 as peripheral output for PWM  and P6.7 for button
 * interrupt */
MAP_GPIO_setAsPeripheralModuleFunctionOutputPin(GPIO_PORT_P2, GPIO_PIN4,
    GPIO_PRIMARY_MODULE_FUNCTION);
redirect();


/* Configuring P1.0 as output */
MAP_GPIO_setAsOutputPin(GPIO_PORT_P1, GPIO_PIN0);
MAP_GPIO_setOutputLowOnPin(GPIO_PORT_P1, GPIO_PIN0);


/* Configuring Timer_A to have a period of approximately 500ms and
 * an initial duty cycle of 10% of that (3200 ticks)  */
//MAP_Interrupt_enableSleepOnIsrExit();
MAP_Interrupt_enableInterrupt(INT_TA0_0);
MAP_Timer_A_generatePWM(TIMER_A0_BASE,&pwmConfig);
MAP_Timer_A_clearInterruptFlag(TIMER_A0_BASE);
MAP_Timer_A_enableInterrupt(TIMER_A0_BASE);
                       MAP_Timer_A_enableCaptureCompareInterrupt
 (TIMER_A0_BASE,TIMER_A_CAPTURECOMPARE_REGISTER_0);

/* Enabling MASTER interrupts */
MAP_Interrupt_enableMaster();  

/* Sleeping when not in use */
while (1)
{
    //MAP_PCM_gotoLPM0();
}
 }


  const int bit_length = 33;
  int period;
  int times[33]; 
  int values[32];  

  x=598;
  number_bit=10;
 // this function - period,times,values
 // x is the 32 bit integer , number_bit is how many bits in    that integer
void int_To_Arr(uint32_t x,int number_bit){

int i = 0;  
period = BIT_LENGTH * 67  ;   // 15fps -> 1/15=66.67m

for (i = 0; i < number_bit ; i++) {
    if (((x >> i) & 1) == 0)    /* shift right by i-bits, check on/off */
        values[i] = 1000;       /* assign to values[i] based on result */
    else
        values[i] = 11000;
    times[i] = BIT_LENGTH * i;  /* set times[i] */
}
 times[i] = BIT_LENGTH * i;   

 }


 void TA0_0_IRQHandler(void)
  {
    int i,value;

    MAP_Timer_A_clearCaptureCompareInterrupt(TIMER_A0_BASE,
         TIMER_A_CAPTURECOMPARE_REGISTER_0);

   time=time+1;
   if(time>=period){
    time=0;
    MAP_GPIO_toggleOutputOnPin(GPIO_PORT_P1, GPIO_PIN0);
    }

   for(i=0;times[i]!=-1;i++){
    if(times[i]>time){
        break;
    }
    value=values[i];
  }

MAP_Timer_A_setCompareValue(TIMER_A0_BASE,TIMER_A_CAPTURECOMPARE_REGISTER_1,  value);

 }
```

So this function will take x (32-bit integer) and number_bit(how many bits in the integer) and will fill the array in the main. if the bit is 1 , values = 11000 which will turn on the led. if the bit is 0 ,values =1000 .Unfortunately, the LED doesnt blink or do anything. Before this I do it manually, yes the LED blinking.

```
int time=0;
const int BIT_LENGTH = 33;
int period;
int times[33]; //{x}
int values[32];//{y}

//new 1001010110
  const int period=667; //15fps - bitlength*67
  const int times[]={0,67,200,267,333,400,467,600,667,-1};
  const int values[]={11000,1000,11000,1000,11000,1000,11000,1000};
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.

Comment: i tried to edit the text below the box but it doesnt change anything. but let me clarify here. do I need to put that x>>i or x<<i for shifting the bit? or actually the loop will shift the bit?

Comment: What result are you getting with the way you have it now?  If it differs from what you want to accomplish, please explain what you are seeing and how it is different from what you want.

Comment: Actually i havent tested it because i need to combine it with bluetooth code. Im using CCS Cloud to do this. I need to make sure im doing the right thing before i tested it.

Comment: Well, I would certainly devise a way to test it before integrating it with other code.  Can you not call if from main here and great a simple console app or something and see how your code works?

Comment: this function will create a pattern for LED. if the bit is 1, LED wil be on and if it is 0, LED will turn off. so i need to make sure the loop is doing the right thing before i upload the code to the circuit

Comment: i cant think of any simple console app to test the code.

Comment: In whatever environment you are coding, can you not compile a simple program and run it?

Comment: simple program? i mean i can save and run the code but i need to combine it with bluetooth code because in the bluetooth code, there is a program called project zero where we can enter integer and do all the stuffs.

Comment: still i wanna know whether im on the right track or else because im kinda confused about the shifting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If through the extended discussions we have had, you are seeking to fill the `values` array based on the `number_bits` in the `uint32_t x` value passed to your `int_to_array` function by shifting the value `x` to the right `number_bits` times and at each iteration determining whether that bit in `x` is `0` or `1` and setting `values[i] = 1000` if the bit is `0` and to `11000` if the bit is `1`, then you could do something like the following:

```
#define BIT_LENGTH 33   /* if you need a constant, define one (or more) */
#define FPS_MULT   33
...
/* fill values based on nbits bit-values in x, 
 * fill times based on BIT_LENGTH and index.
 * note: CHAR_BIT defined in limits.h
 * (defined as 8 for virtually all common systems)
 */
void int_to_array (uint32_t x, int nbits)
{
    int i = 0;  /* loop variable - can be declared in loop for C99+ */
    period = BIT_LENGTH * FPS_MULT;     // your 30fps-1/30=0.033

    /* validate nbits <= 32 */
    if (nbits > (int)(sizeof x * CHAR_BIT)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: nbits out of range of uint32_t\n");
        return;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < nbits; i++) {
        if (((x >> i) & 1) == 0)    /* shift right by i-bits, check on/off */
            values[i] = 1000;       /* assign to values[i] based on result */
        else
            values[i] = 11000;
        times[i] = BIT_LENGTH * i;  /* set times[i] */
    }
    times[i] = BIT_LENGTH * i;      /* final times[BIT_LENGTH - 1] */
}
```

While I am still unclear where those values come from, based on our discussion, that should be what you are looking for. Otherwise, I'm still uncertain. **note** I have added a validation check to insure `nbits` cannot exceed `32` (the number of bits in `x`)

---

**Validation Test**

If you wanted to write a short bit of validation code for your function, you could just write a short program that passes the value provided on the command line as the first argument to your function as `x` (`nbits` won't change, it will always be `sizeof x * CHAR_BIT`). The following code passes the first argument to the function (passing `10` by default if no argument is given on the command line)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define BIT_LENGTH 33   /* if you need a constant, define one (or more) */
#define FPS_MULT   33

int period;
int times[BIT_LENGTH]; 
int values[BIT_LENGTH - 1];

/* fill values based on nbits bit-values in x, 
 * fill times based on BIT_LENGTH and index.
 * note: CHAR_BIT defined in limits.h
 * (defined as 8 for virtually all common systems)
 */
void int_to_array (uint32_t x, int nbits)
{
    int i = 0;  /* loop variable - can be declared in loop for C99+ */
    period = BIT_LENGTH * FPS_MULT;     // your 30fps-1/30=0.033

    /* validate nbits <= 32 */
    if (nbits > (int)(sizeof x * CHAR_BIT)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: nbits out of range of uint32_t\n");
        return;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < nbits; i++) {
        if (((x >> i) & 1) == 0)    /* shift right by i-bits, check on/off */
            values[i] = 1000;       /* assign to values[i] based on result */
        else
            values[i] = 11000;
        times[i] = BIT_LENGTH * i;  /* set times[i] */
    }
    times[i] = BIT_LENGTH * i;      /* final times[BIT_LENGTH - 1] */
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    unsigned long tmp = argc > 1 ? strtoul (argv[1], NULL, 0) : 10;
    uint32_t x;
    int i, nbits = sizeof x * CHAR_BIT;

    if (errno || tmp > UINT32_MAX) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: conversion error or value out of range.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    x = (uint32_t)tmp;

    int_to_array (x, nbits);

    printf ("x: %u\n\nperiod: %d\n\n", x, period);
    for (i = 0; i < nbits; i++)
        printf ("values[%2d]: %5d    times[%2d]: %5d\n",
                i, values[i], i, times[i]);

    printf ("                     times[%2d]: %5d\n", i, times[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** I tweaked the function by addition optional parenthesis to a check to get rid of a `-pedantic` signed/unsigned comparison warning and added a final `times[i] = BIT_LENGTH * i;` after the loop to handle `times` having 1 more element than `values`)

**Example Test**

Simple default value of `10 (1010)`

```
$ ./bin/values_times
x: 10

period: 1089

values[ 0]:  1000    times[ 0]:     0
values[ 1]: 11000    times[ 1]:    33
values[ 2]:  1000    times[ 2]:    66
values[ 3]: 11000    times[ 3]:    99
values[ 4]:  1000    times[ 4]:   132
values[ 5]:  1000    times[ 5]:   165
values[ 6]:  1000    times[ 6]:   198
values[ 7]:  1000    times[ 7]:   231
values[ 8]:  1000    times[ 8]:   264
values[ 9]:  1000    times[ 9]:   297
values[10]:  1000    times[10]:   330
values[11]:  1000    times[11]:   363
values[12]:  1000    times[12]:   396
values[13]:  1000    times[13]:   429
values[14]:  1000    times[14]:   462
values[15]:  1000    times[15]:   495
values[16]:  1000    times[16]:   528
values[17]:  1000    times[17]:   561
values[18]:  1000    times[18]:   594
values[19]:  1000    times[19]:   627
values[20]:  1000    times[20]:   660
values[21]:  1000    times[21]:   693
values[22]:  1000    times[22]:   726
values[23]:  1000    times[23]:   759
values[24]:  1000    times[24]:   792
values[25]:  1000    times[25]:   825
values[26]:  1000    times[26]:   858
values[27]:  1000    times[27]:   891
values[28]:  1000    times[28]:   924
values[29]:  1000    times[29]:   957
values[30]:  1000    times[30]:   990
values[31]:  1000    times[31]:  1023
                     times[32]:  1056
```

or a larger value, `0xdeadbeef (11011110101011011011111011101111)`

```
$ ./bin/values_times 0xdeadbeef
x: 3735928559

period: 1089

values[ 0]: 11000    times[ 0]:     0
values[ 1]: 11000    times[ 1]:    33
values[ 2]: 11000    times[ 2]:    66
values[ 3]: 11000    times[ 3]:    99
values[ 4]:  1000    times[ 4]:   132
values[ 5]: 11000    times[ 5]:   165
values[ 6]: 11000    times[ 6]:   198
values[ 7]: 11000    times[ 7]:   231
values[ 8]:  1000    times[ 8]:   264
values[ 9]: 11000    times[ 9]:   297
values[10]: 11000    times[10]:   330
values[11]: 11000    times[11]:   363
values[12]: 11000    times[12]:   396
values[13]: 11000    times[13]:   429
values[14]:  1000    times[14]:   462
values[15]: 11000    times[15]:   495
values[16]: 11000    times[16]:   528
values[17]:  1000    times[17]:   561
values[18]: 11000    times[18]:   594
values[19]: 11000    times[19]:   627
values[20]:  1000    times[20]:   660
values[21]: 11000    times[21]:   693
values[22]:  1000    times[22]:   726
values[23]: 11000    times[23]:   759
values[24]:  1000    times[24]:   792
values[25]: 11000    times[25]:   825
values[26]: 11000    times[26]:   858
values[27]: 11000    times[27]:   891
values[28]: 11000    times[28]:   924
values[29]:  1000    times[29]:   957
values[30]: 11000    times[30]:   990
values[31]: 11000    times[31]:  1023
                     times[32]:  1056
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: do you know how to test this?

Comment: Sure, just pass `x=10`  (binary `1010`) and `nbits=32` and your values array would hold `{ 1000, 11000, 1000, 11000, 1000, ....}`. `times` array would hold `{0, 33, 66, 99, ..., 1056}`.

Comment: Also note that if `nbits` is ever less than `sizeof x * CHAR_BIT`, you will simply leave all elements of `values` with indexes greater than or equal to `nbits` set to their default initialized value of `0`. (so in theory you could pass `nbits` as `sizeof x * CHAR_BIT - clz(x)` to just set the bits up to the most significant bit in `x` (`clz()` is a system function to 'count leading zeros')

Comment: uhm, is the code reading the bit from the most left or the most right ? if10010, does the code start at 0?

Comment: Of course, but it is simple to reverse. If that's needed, I'll drop a 3rd example.

Comment: and in your example "0xdeadbeef " is considered as 32 bit integer ? :o

Comment: Is the times array in the right order and just the values array that needs to be reversed?

Comment: well before this i used to blink the LED manually by setting up the array on my own                                                                                             //for example 1001010110
// const int period=1000;
// const int times[]={0,100,300,400,500,600,700,900,-1};
// const int values[]={11000,1000,11000,1000,11000,1000,11000,1000};

Comment: Before I post an update, let me make sure I know what you are looking for. When dealing with bits, the bits are indexed as {31, 30 ... 2, 1, 0}` where bit 32 (at bit index 31) is the **most significant bit** and the 1st bit (at bit index 0) is the **least significant bit**. Do you want `values` to be ordered with the **least significant bit** at `values[31]`?

Comment: im getting confused now  but my lecturer once told me it is up to me to decide whether i want to read it from the most left or most right.

Comment: What you show is backwards to convention. You can reverse the bits, but it is a odd way to do it.

Comment: If it were me. I would use standard convention. The lights don't care. They just need to go on/off. The sequence is important. (you can't send Morse code backwards). So you have to decide how you want to do it. The way you show will be quite a bit more complicated.

Comment: Your choice is wise. Otherwise, you would have to iterate over bits from 31 to zero and only start indexing values when you reached the first `1-bit` - doable, just a bit more involved.

Comment: thanks for the help, i will combine my code with bluetooth tonight and will see if it works as i wanted. btw, have you heard of LFSR?

Comment: Not until I just looked it up now. The wikipedia page has a C example. It is indexed the same way I have indexed above (with the nth bit indexed as the nth element of the array)

Comment: "The wikipedia page has a C example. It is indexed the same way I have indexed above (with the nth bit indexed as the nth element of the array)" kinda lost here. are u talking about lfsr or ?

Comment: my lecturer told me that i need to understand LFSR first before doing the function but i've googled about it and found that LFSR just for generating random numbers. I still dont know why he asked me to study about LFSR before coding all this.

Comment: From the function, it looks like he is talking about the coefficients `x^16 + x^14 + ...0` corresponding to the bits which is what is set up in the values array.

Comment: and btw if you are wondering what im working on. We going to have something like home automation. A phone camera will detect the home appliance ( fan/light/or something else) via bluetooth and a menu will pop up to control it.

Comment: and for each home appliance, they will have different led blinking patterns so that the phone camera can detect which is which

Comment: This will all fall into place. You have made the right choice with C. If you want to learn to program, you learn C. If you want to learn a language, then learn C++ or Java. By working at the bit level in C, you will be a much better programmer regardless what language you end up using, because you will understand the hardware at the bit-level. Something largely missed by those who learn another language.

Comment: I have tried to add x and number_Bit globally (outside the function) to test the function but unfortunately my LED doesnt blink. Do you know what might have made it to turn out like that?

Comment: Whether the values are global or not won't matter. You can edit your question and *add your new code at the end* and I'll take a look. There must be something else that is the cause. (a good reboot of the board may be in order too)

Comment: Sure, you only get **One** `times[]` and **One** `values[]` declaration. You already have `int times[33];` and `int values[32];`. If you want to change the declarations to `const int times[]` and `const int values[]`, then you have to **remove** the other declarations. **Note:** by declaring them `const` you cannot change their values, so your function will be useless. These are fairly basic concepts. Always compile with **warnings enabled** (e.g. gcc/clang `-Wall -Wextra`, VS `/W2` and do not accept code until it compiles without warning. The compiler will help you find the problems.

Comment: i still dont understand. what do you mean by  "Note: by declaring them const you cannot change their values, so your function will be useless." and will the LED blink according to the patternn if i change that to const int times[] and const int values[]?

Comment: Whether they are `const` are not does not effect what values are contained in the arrays, it affect whether you can change the values after you initialize them. If you declare them constant, they will only contain the values you initialize the arrays holding. You cannot thereafter change them -- they are constant. Omit the `const` and they are simply arrays, they hold the same values, but you can now change the values they hold as you like.

Comment: [C11 Standard - 6.7.3 Type qualifiers](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.3) explains the `const` qualifier. (bookmark the standard - it is cryptic at first, but it is the end-all reference for all things C). That being said, I think things would go much easier for you if you separate C from the blinking lights for a while. The board has an API (application programming interface) that defines how to make the lights blink. C is the language you are working with. It has basic requirements too. Don't try to do so much all at once. Start slow, take it step by step.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to examine each bit of `x` and see if it is `1` or `0`, using `>>` is correct however doing

```
x>>i; //x<<i
if(x&1==0){
```

will not work because `x>>i` just returns what the value of `x` shifted `i` bits is, it does not update the value of `x`.  Instead, I would do the following

```
x = x >> 1;
if(x&1==0){
```

It will shift the value of `x` by one each time through the loop and then check the rightmost bit.

Also, your loop counter is incorrect, instead of

```
for(i=1;i<x;i++){
```

You most likely want

```
for(i = 1; i < number_bit; i++) {
```

Actually looking at this again, you special case setting `times[0]` and `values[0]` outside the loop, and then start your loop at `1`, so if you want to keep the code structured like that, your loop counter must be

```
for(i = 1; i < number_bit - 1; i++) {
```

Though looking at the code, I see no reason to special case the setting of `times[0]` and `values[0]`, if you examine it closely, you'll see you can loop from

```
for(i = 0; i < number_bit; i++) {
```

and include setting `times[0]` and `values[0]` within the loop.  You would just have to do the shift AFTER setting `values` or use an `if` to not shift `x` when `i` is `0`.